# Using Spring Specification with Date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can I use Spring Specification with Date field? I have no problem with 'normal' fields like Strings. But when I have Date, I have a problem and can't find a solution to solve it.

Here is my TaskEntity.class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASKS")
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private StatusEntity status;

    private Date expiryDate;

    // ....
}
```

And here is my TaskSpecification.class:

```java
public class TaskSpecification implements Specification<TaskEntity> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TaskSpecification.class.getName());

    private List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteriaList;

    public TaskSpecification() {
        this.searchCriteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        searchCriteriaList.add(criteria);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<TaskEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        LOGGER.info("toPredicate()");
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SearchCriteria criteria : searchCriteriaList) {
            if (criteria.getValue() instanceof Date) {
                // WHAT TO DO HERE?
            } else {
                predicates.add(
                        builder.equal(
                                root.get(criteria.getKey()),
                                criteria.getValue().toString())
                );
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("toPredicate(...)");
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `expiryDate` in `TaskEntity` not have a Temporal annotation? Is it a date, date+time or just time? Also you really should just change it to use the `java.time` classes if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ihe same problem I faced a month ago but this `solution` solved my issue.

```java
public static Date startDate(Date date) {
    try {
        DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String strDate = df2.format(date) + "T00:00:00";

        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate);

        Instant instant = localDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        date = Date.from(instant);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return date;
}
```

Create a function and call where you use the date.
like that
`values.add(EntitiesSpecification.startDate(fr.getValues().get(0)));`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the date value and add the date format in entity like MM-DD-YYYY. Could you please try this way?